# NSSegmentedControl does not dim template images

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a `NSSegmentedControl` set to work like a button (mode `Momentary`) with template image icons, but unlike `NSButton`s the images do not change/dim when the window e.g. loses key. To illustrate the problem, look at the image below. Those are all template image assets from the `xcasset` catalog, but only the `NSButton` dims its template image properly.

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you have two separate images (for selected and for not selected), and they won't apply?

Comment: No, I have the segmented control set up like a button (mode `Momentary`), and want it behave like a button. But the template images/icons do not dim like they would on a `NSButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the segmented control to style `Textured Rounded` for the tint to work correctly.